# Can JSON be sent with HttpClient in C# using the PATCH verb?

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I am working with an API that requires a call with the PATCH verb. I am trying to issue a request using the HttpClient object in C#. The request sends, however the JSON is not present in the body. Instead it is blank. Relevant code below.

```
var patch = new HttpMethod("PATCH");
var http = new HttpRequestMessage(patch, "https://apiendpoint");
var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
http.Content = content;

var result = client.SendAsync(http).Result;
```

This is my first time using SendAsync, so perhaps I am missing something else that needs to be set on the HttpRequestMessage?

Comment: How are you verifying that the body is blank?  By checking the `http` variable before sending?

Comment: I have a proxy that I am using to intercept the request, so I can inspect it before it is sent to the server.

Comment: So you have done no actual debugging in the IDE?

Comment: I have, but everything seems in order there. Is there a property on the StringContent/HttpRequestMessage I can check to see if the JSON is in fact there?

Comment: If you see the value in the object before you send, but you arent seeing it in your proxy, maybe there is something wrong with your proxy setup?

Comment: I was thinking that too, but other verbs (POST,GET) are working just fine. Maybe it doesn't like PATCH.  I'll take it out and see what type of response I get from the server.

Comment: Yep, that looks like it was the issue. Very strange. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Strange indeed.  Glad you figured it out